# Importing spreadsheet CSV file with coordinates into QGIS

Tags: qgis

I watched a simple video tutorial on how to accomplish it, but nothing shows up on my project when I add the layer. Even if I try zoom to layer, the screen just shows blue. I'm not sure if it has something to do with my Excel, computer, or program. I really need help as I am new to QGIS.

[image]

Comment: In Excel format your cells to number (6 decimal places) rather than General

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates are in `ESRI:54101`? Try to use `EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic` as "Geometry CRS".